# Throw Exception in Flutter Test

Tags: flutter, testing, flutter-test

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfEKPKKy9dA&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iYGE_khpXRdJkJEp9WOech&index=6) tutorial for Clean Architecture in flutter

This is my **test** file

```dart
test(
        'should return server failure when call to remote data is unsuccessful',
            () async {
          // arrange
          when(mockRemoteDataSource.getConcreteNumberTrivia(any))
          .thenThrow(ServerException());

          // act
          final result = await repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber);

          // assert
          verify(mockRemoteDataSource.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber));
          verifyZeroInteractions(mockLocalDataSource); // <--- this line is failing
          expect(result, equals(Left(ServerFailure()))); // // <--- this line is failing
        },
      );
```

This is my **code**

```dart
Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>> getConcreteNumberTrivia(int number) async {
    networkInfo.isConnected;

    try {
      final remoteTrivia = await remoteDataSource.getConcreteNumberTrivia(number);
      localDataSource.cacheNumberTrivia(remoteTrivia);
      return Right(remoteTrivia);
    } on ServerException {
      return Left(ServerFailure());
    }
  }
```

I dont know why but coz of these 2 lines, test case is failing.

```
verifyZeroInteractions(mockLocalDataSource);
expect(result, equals(Left(ServerFailure())));
```

I have mentioned in test case to throw a server exception using `when` and `thenThrow` but still it goes to this line `localDataSource.cacheNumberTrivia(remoteTrivia);`. I think this is the cause of the error but I am not quite sure.

I did read the docs but I could not find why is this problem occuring. What am i doing wrong? I am new to TDD in flutter. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please provide a complete example that can reproduce the problem.  For example, you haven't shown how you made your code use the mocked objects.

Comment: @jamesdlin This is my [number_trivia_repository_impl.dart](https://pastebin.com/16TYHAPc) file and this is my [number_trivia_repository_impl_test.dart](https://pastebin.com/wN5HAxxD) file

Answer (score 0):

**verifyZeroInteractions(mockLocalDataSource);**

Fail is normal because you called it in you `getConcreteNumberTrivia` function (`localDataSource.cacheNumberTrivia`) and you are expecting in your test no interaction. Just remove it, it should pass.

**expect(result, equals(Left(ServerFailure())));**

For the this one, can you try this ?

```
   result.fold((left) {
       expect(left, isA<ServerFailure>());
    }, (r) => fail("test failed"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear Interactions for mockLocalDataSource at the beginning of the test

This way:
`clearInteractions(mockLocalDataSource);`